# Java IllegalArgumentException in Zip FileSystem

Tags: java, zip, illegalargumentexception

I have a simple application which unzips a large number of Zip Files. It uses Files.walkFileTree() to walk the folders required and unzip them into an output folder.

There are over 1600 zip files. In a very few cases (3 to be precise) I get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MALFORMED[1]
    at jdk.zipfs/jdk.nio.zipfs.ZipCoder.toString(ZipCoder.java:90)
    at jdk.zipfs/jdk.nio.zipfs.ZipCoder$UTF8.toString(ZipCoder.java:64)
    at jdk.zipfs/jdk.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystem.getString(ZipFileSystem.java:938)
    at jdk.zipfs/jdk.nio.zipfs.ZipPath.toString(ZipPath.java:603)
    at utilities.DazUnzipper$2.visitFile(DazUnzipper.java:149)
    at utilities.DazUnzipper$2.visitFile(DazUnzipper.java:1)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2724)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2796)
    at utilities.DazUnzipper.unZip(BatchUnzipper.java:146)
    at utilities.DazUnzipper.run(BatchUnzipper.java:104)
    at utilities.DazUnzipper.main(BatchUnzipper.java:171)
```

In all of these failure cases, the zip file in question unzips without error using 7Zip.

I am using OpenJDK11. I have looked at the source of ZipCoder, and I am stumped. The toString() method takes a byte array as input, does some manipulation oif the byte array, checks the return code from a CoderResult.isUnderflow(), and throws IllegalArgumentException if it is false.

To quote from the doc:

"Underflow is reported when there is no more input to be processed, or there is insufficient input and additional input is required. This condition is represented by the unique result object UNDERFLOW, whose isUnderflow method returns true."

Comment: Well, 7zip can open way more formats or varieties of zip-files than Java's zip library (iirc certain compression/encryption methods are not or at least have not been supported). That might be the problem `ZipCoder` runs into.

Comment: Using 7zip I unzipped the file into a folder, and then created a new zip file from the results. It raises the same error. Many of these 1600 zips are created using 7zip, all using default settings, but do not fail.

Comment: Most likely, you have filenames in the zip file which are not using UTF-8 for non-ASCII characters.  Try putting the correct charset name in the zip filesystem’s environment when you create it, under the key `"encoding"`.  For instance, `envMap.put("encoding", "ISO_8559_1");`.

Comment: Re my previous comment, The new zip file I created on this system, US English, had its name typed in by me on a US English keyboard, and it raised the same error. No thing but ASCII in the filenames. Nevertheless I will consider putting UTF-8 in there for completeness sake.